# Help identifying this bug

Tags: pest-control, pests

I recently noticed several of these bugs on one of my backyard trees. It seemed to be feeding at a wound in the bark. It appears beetle-like with a shell covering its wings. They range in size from about a quarter inch to three-quarters o an inch. I live in West central Florida.  Does anyone know what it is and whether it is harmful?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the photo is very dark so its hard to see detail, can you brighten it up and repost it?

Comment: Just put up a few more photos.

Comment: What tree is it?

Comment: It's a Bulnesia sp. not sure of any common or species name.

Comment: I am starting to think it may be some species of long horned beetle.